# How to get shipping in smarty?

Tags: smarty

Is possible to make an condition in smarty?
In .tpl file i got only {cart_product_price} to print current cartprice.
For example:

```
if ({cart_product_price} > 350){
echo 'shipping free';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course You can. Check this:

```
{if $cart_product_price > 350}
    something...
{else}
    something else...
{/if}
```

Or

```
{if ( $cart_product_price < 0 or $cart_product_price > 350 ) }
   ...
{/if}
```

Check more on Smarty documentation page:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl